# apt no longer processing triggers

Tags: apt

I got a small update this morning to install, but apt now gets stuck on processing triggers. I don't know why this is a problem all of the sudden.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade --autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.10.0-10-amd64
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libexpat1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/98.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 302 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 152993 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.10.0-10-amd64 (5.10.84-1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-10-amd64
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-12-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-11-amd64
done
(Reading database ... 148225 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.2.10-2+deb11u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.10-2+deb11u3) over (2.2.10-2+deb11u2) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.10-2+deb11u3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
^C
```

It didn't timeout and I have the same problem when I try to reinstall it:

```
$ sudo apt install libexpat1 --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/98.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 148225 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.2.10-2+deb11u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.10-2+deb11u3) over (2.2.10-2+deb11u3) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.10-2+deb11u3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
^C
```

I can still remove and install a small package like curl even though it hangs the same way again:

```
$ sudo apt remove curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  curl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 436 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 148225 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing curl (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...

$ sudo apt install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/267 kB of archives.
After this operation, 436 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
(Reading database ... 148217 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.74.0-1.3+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u1) ...
Setting up curl (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
^C

$ curl --version
curl 7.74.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-12-09
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Here's some general information about the system:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
11.2

$ apt --version
apt 2.2.4 (amd64)

$ uname -a
Linux <system> 5.10.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.103-1 (2022-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestions what to check next?

Answer (score 1):

By using `pstree` and looking at the children of the `apt` process, I was able to find a needrestart process that had hung:

```
        |-systemd-+-(sd-pam)
        |         |-apt---sh---needrestart
```

But the needrestart hanged the machine so heavily that I couldn't do normal commands like ps to get the PID to kill it. I solved it with the big hammer and rebooted the whole machine.

After the reboot, all commands work as expected and no installation seems to have gone wrong. Not even libexpat1 is listed as a partially installed package by the --audit command:

```
$ sudo dpkg --audit
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).